# In Android Studio the widgets are moving up on the screen during emulation

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I am new to both Stack Overflow and Android Studio and learning to code now.

I did a basic user and password layout in Android Studio like this:

[image: layout i tried.]

When I ran this on emulator, it displays the widgets like this:

[image: screen shot]

I tried to change the width of the `EditText` fields, buttons, but nothing I have tried seems to be working.

How do I solve this?

What am I missing or am I doing something wrong ?

Layout code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="233dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/worldcurrency" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter ammount"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dollar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="convert"
        android:text="Convert" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rupees"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your `xml` layout please?

Comment: @magicleon I have included the layout code now. sorry for the late update.

Comment: no problem, I've answered below!

Answer (score 0):

Your layout's parent is a `ConstraintLayout`, but it's lacking every constraint. `ConstraintLayout` is characterised by the ability to set constraints to every view, forcing its behaviour across screens of different sizes and orientations. 
If you really want to use a `ConstraintLayout` I suggest taking a look at the [ConstraintLayout Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). 
Once you've properly set the constraints, you should have an `xml` like [this](https://github.com/magicleon94/Popular-Movies-Stage-2/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/detail_constraint.xml) (note the `constraint*` attributes in my `Views`.
So, your layout has no constraints, it's likely it will end at "random" positions. Moreover, you've set the views coordinates with `tools`, which is valid only for the layout preview, not for runtime. And moreover, the use of `absolute` coordinates is very not recommended, since it can cause problems across different screen sizes.

If `ConstraintLayout` is an optional choice for you, you can change the layout parent to a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation, I think it's more suitable for the layout you're building (I'm assuming this by your screenshots).
Hope I helped, let me know. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed the layout to linear but now I get just a blank screen after running the emulator. 
(`(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"> `)

Comment: It seems good to me... Maybe Android is not using the right resource. What folder is your layout in? Is it `res/layout`? I'm sorry for my delayed responses, I have a test the day after tomorrow and I answer when I have  some time to spend in StackOverflow :(

Comment: Oh, and try to remove the `android:weightsum` attribute, I've got this hunch